Fourier series related to the floor function
I'm trying to find the Fourier series for the periodic function:
$$f(x)=\left \lfloor nx\right \rfloor-n\left \lfloor x\right \rfloor\;\;\;\;\;n\in \mathbb{N}$$
$\left \lfloor \cdot \right \rfloor$ being the floor function. By Hermite's Identity, we have:
$$\left \lfloor nx\right \rfloor-n\left \lfloor x\right \rfloor=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left \lfloor x+\frac{k}{n}\right \rfloor-\left \lfloor x\right \rfloor=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(x+\frac{k}{n}-\left\{x+\frac{k}{n} \right\}\right)-\left(x-\left\{x \right\}\right)$$
where $\left\{\cdot \right\}$ is the fractional part function. Thus:
$$f(x)=\frac{n-1}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left\{x \right\}-\left\{x+\frac{k}{n} \right\}$$
Using the Fourier series of the fractional part function:
$$\left\{x \right\}=\frac{1}{2}-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2\pi m x)}{m\pi}$$
We obtain:
$$f(x)=\frac{n-1}{2}+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m\pi}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\left(2\pi m\left(x+\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)-\sin(2\pi m x)\right)$$
$$=\frac{n-1}{2}-n\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2\pi m x)}{m\pi}=n\left\{x \right\}-\frac{1}{2}$$
Which gives the wrong answer! Where did I go wrong?

You dropped the $n$ from $n \lfloor x \rfloor$ in the first step.

No, I didn't. I subtracted $\left \lfloor x\right \rfloor$ $n$ times.

The sum is from $1$ to $n-1$ so you're short one $\lfloor x \rfloor$.

True, but the sum in Hermite's identities begins at $k=0$, so that was accounted for.

What is the right answer? Also, isn't it easier to use the Fourier series of the floor function directly?

The right answer is some sort of a staircase function, as opposed to a sawtooth function.
